# Use value_counts with a groupby function based on a condition in pandas dataframe and insert into a new column

Tags: pandas, lambda, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have a large data set with multiple rows, shown in the picture attached. I am trying to get a `value_counts` to get the sum of `Males` and `Females` (in the `gender` column), per `Country`. I also need to have a condition where the `Hague` field is a `Yes` or `No`. So there is a `Male/No` and a `Male/Yes`, with the same for `Female`. I am trying to use a groupby function on the `countries` and `Hague`, with the formula below:

```
data_df.groupby('Country')['Gender'].apply(lambda x: x[x== 'M'].count())
```

Using this, I can get the count of a specific `gender`, per `country`, but I cannot figure out the condition to make the `Hague` a '`YES`' and '`NO`'.

I have also figured out how to only bring the rows where you can select a particular gender and Hague status. But I cannot figure out how to count the amount of male/female in the gender column

```
data_df.loc[(data_df['Hague'] =='NO') & (data_df['Gender'] =='M')]
```

[Image of the main dataset called data_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAi3x.png)

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and ease to answer it.

Comment: I edited the original question, I hope this helps. I am new to this

Comment: no prob, that's why the hint. btw, you could make the answerer happy, if you vote his answer. Btw, please take sometime, and read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and enjoy the site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood you but please try. Let us know if it is contrary and we will help

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Hague':['NO', 'YES', 'YES','YES','YES','YES','YES','NO','YES'],'Country':['AFGHANISTAN', 'ALBANIA', 'ALBANIA','ALBANIA','ALBANIA','ALBANIA','ALBANIA','ANTIGUA AND BARBUD','ARMENIA'],'Age':[12,2,4,3,3,9,3,12,1],'Gender':['M', 'M', 'M','F','M','F','M','F','M']})
```

Filter Hague/Gender

```
  df[((df['Hague']=='YES')& (df['Gender']=='M'))].groupby('Country')['Gender'].value_counts()
```

Outcome

[image]

Comment: I tried it and got an index error ( IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 0 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1)

Comment: Please send me a sample of your data. Maybe you columns are differently named or we have different dtypes. Happy to help

Comment: I also tried data_df[(data_df['Hague']=='Yes')] & data_df.groupby('Country')['Gender'].value_counts() but I get a ValueError.... cannot join with no overlapping index names

Comment: My solution outputs a dataframe not a series. You cannot assign it to a column. Are you happy to copy paste your data and a brief explanation of what you want so that I help

Comment: Here is a copy of the data. I would like a count of gender in each country. But only when Hague status says NO. That is the part I am confused about, filtering the rows of the Hague column. I know the value_counts() can do this. 

Hague Country Age Gender
NO AFGHANISTAN 12 M
YES ALBANIA 2 M
YES ALBANIA 4 M
YES ALBANIA 3 F
YES ALBANIA 3 M
YES ALBANIA 9 F
YES ALBANIA 3 M
NO ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA 12 F
YES ARMENIA 1 M

I also included a screenshot in original post

Comment: I edited the original question, I hope this helps. I am new to this

Comment: how do I send a sample of data?

Comment: Could you please accept the answer by clicking between the arrows on the left. That way other can use it with confidence and I also get points for my time spent

Comment: Happy or need more help? Happy to continue helping

Comment: I believe I did it correctly. So there is no way to move the results into another column?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @wwnde I have figured out the code!

```
data_df.loc[(data_df['Hague'] =='NO') & (data_df['Gender'] =='M')].groupby('Country')['Gender'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Happy or need more help? Happy to continue helping